# Find location of a Jtree icon

Tags: java, swing, jtree

Here's my problem. I want the pop up dialog to be triggered when a use clicks on the icon and icon only of a jtree tree node. I did some research and did not find any existing way to add mouse listeners on the icon (if there is please let me know!). Therefore, I decided to hack my way into it and use the Point object which I can get form mouseevent.getPoint() to figure out whether the mouse is on the icon. However, when I call Jtree.getCellRenct(row, col, includespacing) the location I get seem to be relative to the indentation of children node. 
For example,

Parent

-Child1

-Child2

I get the same x coordinate by calling getCellRect() on all three nodes although what I really want is the x plus the indentation caused by "-" because mouseevent.getpoint() is not relative to the indentation.

Any idea how I can do this?

**Edit:**

I figured out a way. I call tree.getUI to get a BasicTreeUI object and call BasicTreeUI.getLeftChildIndent() and BasicTreeUI.getRightChildIndent(). Summing up these two integers will be the total indentation per level of the tree (or it seems to be so far). So I calculate the indentation by

```
(path.getPathCount() - 1) * (leftindent + rightindent).
```

It works for me so far although I am not entirely sure if this is good. For example I don't really know what left and right indent mean. Also in the source of BasicTreeUI it actually has a protected method

```
protected int getRowX(int row, int depth) 
{
    return totalChildIndent * (depth + depthOffset);
}
```

This method seems to get called by another protected method used to check if a location is within the area of tree expansion or collapse icon. I couldn't figure out much about what depthOffset is for. I guess it has something to do with whether root gets displayed or things of similar nature.

But still I am not feeling very comfortable doing it this way.. could somebody either tell me I'm good or that there is a better way to do this? :-)

Comment: You need to convert the point to the renderer's coordinate space and determine if the point exists within the bounds of the icon.  You may also need to take into consideration the cell bounds of the renderer using something like `JTree#getRowBounds`

Comment: +1 for reading the api :-) The slight drawback is the typecast to BasicTreeUI - that might fail for rare case that treeUI is not of that type (as might happen f.i. if an auxiliary LAF is added). Other than this, I would go for it. You can answer your own question, btw.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I know for sure the application I am working on will stick with the current LAF so I'm good for now.